# Aligning Class Members in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-alignment

I'm trying to align class members to specific alignments (e.g., 128) in C++11 to avoid false sharing between threads. My approach is to use `alignas` but I'm getting mixed results. In this simple program, I'm getting the results I desire:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <atomic>

struct Foo {

    char foo[128];

    void* x1;
    uint32_t x2;
    uint32_t x3; // here an "entry" is only the

    alignas(128) std::atomic<unsigned int> a;
    alignas(16) std::atomic<unsigned int> b;

};


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

    Foo x, y;

    printf("alignof(Foo x) = %zu\n", alignof(x));
    printf("alignof(Foo x.a) = %zu\tmod 128 = %d\n", alignof(x.a), reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(&(x.a)) % 128);
    printf("alignof(Foo x.b) = %zu\tmod 16 = %d\n", alignof(x.b), reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(&(x.b)) % 16);

    /* code */
    return 0;
}
```

However, in a larger program with a very similar class structure, and also using `alignas` to 128 bytes. When I print out the `alignof` of the fields, I get what I expect and what I specified in the `alignas` attribute. However, when I mod address of the relevant fields, I don't get the same value as the `alignas` argument (128) -- I get 32. **I'm expecting `alignas` to put the variable in memory at the beginning of a memory address that divides evenly by 128; is this expectation valid?**

Note that in the program below, I get the expected results when compiling with clang 6.0.1. I can't post that larger program because it's very large and can't be shared. I also haven't been able to come up with a test program that replicates the particular issue yet but I continue to try.

**Questions:**

- Is my approach to align specific members within a class the recommended one for C++11?
- If not, what is the proper way? Is adding dummy fields such as `char _pad[120]` the way?
- Should I also be aligning the overall class itself? Right now I'm not explicitly doing so.

Comment: _However, in a larger program with a very similar class structure, and also using alignas to 128 bytes, the fields end up coming out as not aligned as specified._ - you need to post an example that demonstrates the behaviour you observe.

Comment: set align to members proper way, if it need. but always need set members with lager align to the front. you need move `a, b` to the begin of class. in your current implementation `sizeof (Foo) == 3*128`, if move a,b to the begin - will be `2*128`. adding dummy fields not proper way, it can not change default align at all